# Why does second const VARNAME not have syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I copied and pasted a .php file and edited it. It went from:

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        const RESET = 'reset';
```

to

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        const RESET = 'reset';
        const USERBIKE = 'userbike';
```

So, it's just literally a like-for-like line using a different var name and value.

However, despite their 98% match, `vim` displays them differently:

[image]

How and why does it do this? How do I go about resolving?

Quick details

- Framework being used here: Magento2 (PHP7)
- Standard Vim on CentOS7

Comment: that is because the `reset` is parsed/detected as the `reset()` function since php functions are case insensitive

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt doh! Makes so much sense, now I just feel silly xD